# OpenMDAO adding command line args for ExternalCodeComp that won't results in runtime error

Tags: openmdao

In OpenMDAO V3.1 I am using an ExternalCodeComp to execute a CFD code.  Typically, I would call it as such:

```
mpirun nodet_mpi --design_run
```

If the above call is made in the appropriate directory, then it will find the appropriate run file and execute the CFD run.  I have tried command args for the ExternalCodeComp;

```
execute = ['mpirun', 'nodet_mpi', '--design_run']
execute = ['mpirun', 'nodet_mpi --design_run']
execute = ['mpirun nodet_mpi --design_run']
```

I either get an error such as:

RunTimeError: 255, execvp error on file "nodet_mpi --design_run" (No such file or directory)

Or that the command cannot be found.

Is there any way to setup the execute statement to include commandline args for the flow solver when an input file is not defined?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: which version of OpenMDAO are you running with?

Comment: I am using version 3.1

Answer (score 1):

One detail in your question seems incorrect, you state that you have tried `execute = "..."`. The ExternalCodeComp uses an [option called `command`](http://openmdao.org/twodocs/versions/3.1.1/features/building_blocks/components/external_code_comp.html#externalcodecomp-options). I will assume that you are using the correct option in your code.

The most correct form to use is the list with all arguments as single entries in the list:
`self.options['command'] = ['mpirun', 'nodet_mpi', '--design_run']`

Your error msg seems to indicate that the directory that OpenMDAO is running in is not the same as the directory you would like to execute the CFD code from. The absolute simplest solution would be to make sure that you are in the correct directory via `cd` in the terminal window before executing your python script.

However, there is likely a reason that your python script is in a different place so there are other options I can suggest:

1. You can use a combination of `os.getcwd()` and `os.chdir()` inside the `compute` method that you have implemented to make sure you switch into and out of the working directory for the CFD code.
2. If you would like to, you can modify the entries of the list you've assigned to the `self.options['command']` option on the fly within your compute method. You would again be relying on some of the methods in the `os` module for help. `os.path.exists` can be used to test if the specific input files you need exist or not, and you can modify the `command` option accordingly.

For option 2, code would look something like this:

```
def compute(self, inputs, outputs):

    if os.path.exists('some_input.file'): 
        self.options['command'] = ['mpirun', 'nodet_mpi', '--design_run']
    else: 
        self.options['command'] = ['mpirun', 'nodet_mpi', '--design_run', '--other_options']

    # the parent compute function actually runs the external code
    super().compute(inputs, outputs)
```